# Android Recyclerview Scrolling to position During Scrolling SeekBar

Tags: android

i listed book paragraphs as `RecyclerView` rows and i'm trying to scrolling to pages by `SeekBar` but sweeping `seekBar` from left to right and right to left return different progress value for example in this code `pagesPositions` is recyclerView positions by found max as `pageCounter` variable, now when i scrolling from left to right `progressValue` starting with `1` and ending with `2` and then when i sweeping right to left `progressValue` starting with `1` and ending with `0`

Logcat:

**left to right:**

```
E/progressValue: 1
E/progressValue: 2
```

**right to left**

```
E/progressValue: 1
E/progressValue: 0
```

how can i fix this problem ?

```
page_number_seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
          //book_content.smoothScrollToPosition(pagesPositions.get(position));
            Log.e("progressValue ", progressValue + "");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
});

pagesPositions = new ArrayList<>();
int pageCounter = 0;
for (int p = 0; p < bookContent.size(); p++) {
    if (bookContent.get(p).getContentType() == 7) {
        pagesPositions.add(p);
        pageCounter++;
    }
}
page_number_seek_bar.setMax(pageCounter);
```